# Equality constraints on type level lists

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, type-level-computation

I'm trying to enforce a type-level constraint that a type-level list must be the same length as a type-level Nat being carried around. For example, using Length from singletons [1] package:

```hs
data (n ~ Length ls) => NumList (n :: Nat) (ls :: [*])

test :: Proxy (NumList 2 '[Bool, String, Int])
test = Proxy
```

I would not expect this code to compile, since there is a mismatch.

EDIT: As dfeuer mentioned Datatype contexts aren't a good idea. I can do the comparison at the value level, but I want to be able to do this at the type level:

```hs
class NumListLen a 
  sameLen :: Proxy a -> Bool

instance (KnownNat n, KnownNat (Length m)) => NumListLen (NumList n m) where
  sameLen = const $ (natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)) == (natVal (Proxy :: Proxy (Length m)))
```

~~~~

EDIT: Sorta answered my own question, simply add the constraint to the instance:

```hs
class NumListLen a 
  sameLen :: Proxy a -> Bool

instance (KnownNat n, KnownNat (Length m), n ~ Length m) => NumListLen (NumList n m) where
  sameLen = const $ (natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)) == (natVal (Proxy :: Proxy (Length m)))
```

```
/home/aistis/Projects/SingTest/SingTest/app/Main.hs:333:13:
    Couldn't match type ‘3’ with ‘2’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘sameLen test’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ sameLen test
    In the expression:
      do { print $ sameLen test;
           putStrLn "done!" }
```

[1] https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.0.0.2/docs/Data-Promotion-Prelude-List.html#t:Length

Comment: That's a datatype context. Datatype contexts are utterly useless. I suspect you're not going to be able to do exactly what you're trying to do in Haskell just yet, but singletons can do some weird stuff....

Comment: Yes, you are right, datatype contexts are not exactly how I would want to do this. But they get the point across. I am able to reify the type value and do the comparison at the value level, but this isn't what I want to do.

Comment: Can you explain a bit better what exactly your ultimate goal is here? What do you want to express, really?

Comment: I just want to be able to take a type level nat and a type level list and check that n ~ Length ls at the type level, I don't want to do it at the value level. I edited my OP with additional details.

Comment: Have you looked at frightening things like `Data.Singletons.Prelude.Eq`? I don't know what to make of that, but there might well be a simpler way.

Answer (score 4):

If this is something like an invariant (which it seems it is), you should store the proof in the datatype:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds, UndecidableInstances #-} 

import GHC.TypeLits 

type family Length (xs :: [k]) :: Nat where 
  Length '[] = 0 
  Length (x ': xs) = 1 + Length xs 

data TList n l where 
  TList :: (Length xs ~ n) => TList n xs
```

Note that while the proof is still available at the type level, it is sort of "hidden" behind the data constructor. You can recover the proof simply by pattern matching:

```
data (:~:) a b where Refl :: a :~: a 

test :: TList n l -> Length l :~: n 
test TList = Refl
```

Now, mismatches between the two parameters are a type error:

```
bad :: TList 3 '[Int, Bool]
bad = TList 

good :: TList 2 '[Int, Bool]
good = TList
```

Of course this can still be beaten by bottom values, so

```
uh_oh :: TList 10 '[] 
uh_oh = undefined
```

To avoid this, simply make sure you always pattern match on the `TList` constructor.

Comment: Excellent, this is pretty close to what I'm looking for!  Although, how do I make this work with Proxy?

Comment: Yes, I want to carry this invariant around. But I don't want to define a separate TList, it should be using Proxy.

Comment: Impossible - the entire point of `Proxy` is it carries no type information. I can't see exactly why you would need to use proxy in particular - you can always produce a `Proxy` anyways . You can of course simply place the constraint where you need it and use `Proxy` there : `Length xs ~ n => Proxy xs -> Proxy n -> ...` but then you don't have the "correct by construction" property.

Comment: Huh, really, to me it seems that Proxy is exactly the opposite of what you said, it's carries no data, it's meant only to hold types. Although I could be completely wrong.

Comment: `Proxy :: Proxy x` is isomorphic to `()` at runtime for any type x. It does not store the type of `x` in any capacity. This is not true for `TList`. At runtime, constraints become concrete values, so the type of `TList` is essentially `TList :: Coercion (Length xs) n -> TList n xs` - `Coercion` is the internal type used by GHC to represent type equalities - it is a runtime witness of the equality of two types, hence, runtime type information.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense!

Comment: You can import `Data.Type.Equality` to get `:~:` instead of defining it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

One option might be to use a type family:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat

type family LengthIs (n :: Nat) (xs :: [*]) :: Bool where
  LengthIs 'Z '[] = 'True
  LengthIs ('S n) (x ': xs) = LengthIs n xs
  LengthIs n xs = 'False

test :: LengthIs ('S ('S 'Z)) '[Bool,String,Int] ~ 'True => ()
test = ()
```

This will not pass the type checker; the only way to make it pass is to make the type list have two elements. I don't know how `Nat` works in the singletons library, but I imagine you might be able to do something similar.

Comment: Good example, but I want to use GHC's builtin type nats. Plus I answered my own question!